# SWC's bundler compiles to ES6 import instead of require

Tags: node.js, typescript, swc-compiler

Is it possible to have SWC bundle TypeScript files whilst transforming ES6 imports to commonjs require()? Not sure if I can not get it to work due to my limited understanding, or whether I am missing a certain option.

Basically, I have an entry TS file that imports an external library via a simple
`import convert from 'xml-js';`. Then, with the following `spack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    type: 'commonjs',
  },
  options: {
    jsc: {
      target: 'es2018',
      parser: {
        syntax: 'typescript',
        // isModule: true,
        // dynamicImport: true,
    },
  },
  externalModules: ['xml-js'],
  entry: {
    'loader': __dirname + '/src/loader.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },
}
```

I would expect the bundle to contain a commonjs require() (due to `type: 'commonjs'`), but instead it results in `import convert from "xml-js";` I have tried a bunch of different config options, but the outcome has been the same every attempt.

When I use Rollup with rollup-plugin-typescript2, it does result in a require():
`var convert = require('xml-js');` This is how I expect SWC's bundler to work too.

My feeling says SWC should be capable of doing this too, but I am not sure how. Any hint in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. [Here's the documentation from the SWC website.](https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/modules)

You've included the required `type: "commonjs"`, but in the wrong place. I haven't used Spack or whatever this config file is but it seems that your file should say this:

```javascript
module.exports = {
  options: {
    module: {
      type: 'commonjs',
    },
    jsc: {
      target: 'es2018',
      parser: {
        syntax: 'typescript',
        // isModule: true,
        // dynamicImport: true,
      }
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

For those using a `.swcrc` config file (remember to remove comments):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs" // can be "es6", "umd", or "amd"
  },
  // any other options
}
```

Comment: this can convert the mjs to cjs only. NOT convert the cjs to mjs!

Comment: @RiceballLEE The question was to convert from MJS to CJS. If you want to convert CJS to MJS, please post a different question.

Comment: See the question title: "SWC's bundler compiles(convert) to ES6 `import`"(ESM: `.mjs`) instead of `require` (commonjs: `cjs`).

Comment: @RiceballLEE You aren't reading it right. "SWC's bundler compiles to ES6 import instead of require" is the problem, it could be better worded as "How to make SWC compile from ES6 to require?"

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for to use in transformFile from swc/core. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem: the current SWC cannot transpiling `require()` of commonjs to `import` of esm. It can only convert esm to commonjs.

```json
{
   "jsc": {
     "target": "esnext",
   }
   "module": {
     "type": "es6"
   },
}
```

BTW: SWC bundler is another related project(currently still in early stage). SWC is the code transpiler.

I've tried `esbuild`, but it still doesn't support transpiling `require`:

```bash
npx esbuild src/custom.cjs --format=esm --outfile=custom.mjs
▲ [WARNING] Converting "require" to "esm" is currently not supported [unsupported-require-call]
```

Maybe only `babel` can currently support: https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs

Finally, currently my conclusion is that if you want to use newer code transpilers such as SWC/esbuild, it's best to write in ESM and translate them into commonjs. Otherwise use the `babel` instead.